# sql function to convert minutes : seconds , hundreds to seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I convert a value that is stored like 01:14,12 into seconds like 74,12 inside a `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT` statement?

i am using mysql

the column is char(10) but i can change this.

Comment: What RDBMS and version?, what datatype is the column?. Please, share more details so you can get an answer

Comment: added more information

Comment: I updated my solution for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select total_seconds =DATEDIFF(second,0,'20:10:10');
```

DATEDIFF should solve your problem.

[Here you can check DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

So just put:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',your_column) blablabla the comparisson you want
```

for MySQL there is a function:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(time)
```

Converts the time '01:14:12' to seconds.

TIME_TO_SEC(time)

```
Returns the time argument, converted to seconds.

mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('22:23:00');
    -> 80580
mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:39:38');
    -> 2378
```

Comment: is it possible with 00:00,00 too?

Comment: Well, now that op updated his question saying that s/he is using MySQL, this won't work

Comment: Just added a solution for MySQL too